# PDO select statement not giving correct data

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm hoping someone can help out here I have this code. I have been using https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/check_email_exists
and other stuff through StackOverflow to try and help me work through this.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT username FROM user_info WHERE username='?'");
$stmt->execute([$username]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is supposedly from everything, I understand return the value from the `select` statement within my **database**

but it always only returns with the value of `bool(false)` and I'm not sure why.
Any help would be value I been stuck on this for the better part of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use ? or : with PDO this way.
Try this mate :

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM user_info WHERE username=:username");
$stmt->execute([":username" => $username]);
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Always "prepare" if you want to use execute().

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help it fixed all of my troubles